# How to start an eigenvalue problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, lebesgue-integral

I am stuck on this problem : This is an eigenvalue problem 
$$\phi''+ \lambda^2 x(x+2)^2 \phi =0\\\phi(1)=0\\ \phi(0)=0$$ I forget  this kind of problems...

Please give me a hint or a clue, cause I don't know how to start.
Thanks in advance.

---

My first idea was to get basis like this $\phi_n(x)=x\left(1-x\right)^n $  and $$\phi(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n \phi_n(x)$$ am I on a right track?

Comment: Well, $\;\phi(x)\equiv 0\;$ is a solution to this initial conditions problem...

Comment: OK ,thanks . but what is next step ?

Comment: Well, it could be to announce "Hey, I already solved this problem!"... If, for example, I try to solve this with Laplace Transform, again I get $\;\phi\equiv0\;$ . Perhaps there's some other way to get *other* solutions, I can't say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess DEQs of this type show up when expressing problems in terms of parabolic cylindrical coordinates.

So you might be looking for Weber DEQs or more generally, parabolic cylinder functions as a basis.

Fitting your problem into this framework, the solution could be

$$
\phi(\lambda, x) = c_1 D_{(-1/2)}((1+i) x^{1/4} \sqrt{x+2} \; \lambda)+c_2 
D_{-1/2}((-1+i) x^{1/4} \sqrt{x+2} \; \lambda)
$$

where $D_n (z)$ are parabolic cylinder functions and the constants should be adapted to the boundary conditions. Wolfram Alpha helps as well.

Hope this goes in the right direction...